# Can さん or 君 be used on animals?

Tags: honorifics, animals

In [Mikan Enikki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikan_Enikki), the protagonist cat was referred to as ネコ**さん** when his name was not known (e.g. Kikuko Kusanagi called him as such when she didn't know his name), and as みかん**君** when someone else talked to his owners (e.g. Dr. Inagaki referred to Mikan as such when he talked to his adoptive mother Kikuko Kusanagi). Are those cases true in real life? Can さん or 君 be used on animals?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that happens ***very*** often in real life when:

1) Small children refer to or address animals.

2) Adults talk to small kids about animals.

Even adults often use 「ちゃん」 and 「君{くん}」 to refer to or address the pets of poeple they know well, which is just like referring to or addressing their friends' kids.

Here are songs about

An elephant (ぞう): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd0SuSTwRdo

A bear (くま): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ2QeebJ8ro

A kitten (こねこ): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CDd938DOaM

Comment: I wasn't asking about ちゃん though.